# Best practice to use a configuration file for Paths, Ports,

Tags: node.js

I have to update and optimize an nodejs Project for some new use cases. For this, i have to easily change the paths for different host systems. Till now they were hardcoded.

First i used global variables, just to get the system running. But globals are not a very clever idea. Now i created a config.js file which includes the paths and in any nodejs file i linked to them with request("config.js").

nodejs
`global.OEM_datapath =  __dirname + '/public/data.csv';

now:

```
config.js
var PATHs = {
    'OEM_datapath': __dirname + '/public/data/data.csv'
}

module.exports = PATHs;

other nodejs files:
var globals = require('./config'); 
console.log("path:" + globals.OEM_datapath);
```

'''

Is there a better way to use configuration settings? I considered to use process.env?

Comment: Why don't you use configuration module https://www.npmjs.com/package/config and setup configurations files for different environments?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is an environment that helps you create server-side applications using JavaScript. One of the common Node.js elements that developers like and use are .env files. These files let you easily save and load environment variables. Developers often use them to store confidential information. However, sometimes they forget to disable access to these files from the outside, which can lead to major security problems. You can create a sperate env file and maintain the dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

> I considered to use process.env

That is the standard way, in fact if you are working with containers, such as Docker this will also be the case. My suggestion would be to use YAML as the config language and derive config from that, again a Docker 'standard'.